# Syntax error identifier when defining a struct in C

Tags: c, compiler-errors, syntax-error

I have defined these structs in a C file and I don't know why I get this compile error.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#include<string.h>

//using namespace std;

typedef struct Gradina{
    char* denumire;
    int nrFlori;
    float* preturi;
}Gradina;

typedef struct Nod {
    Gradina* info;
    Nod* next, * prev; //the first syntax error points here
}Nod; //the second error points here
```

I'm getting 37 syntax errors and I don't know why.
I'm using Visual Studio 2022.
[image]

Comment: If you change to the `Output` tab you will get the build output (including the errors) as text. Please copy-paste the *text* into your questions. And please try to create a proper [mre] to show us, and add comments in the code on the exact lines where you get the errors.

Comment: As a hint, when is the **type-alias** `Nod` defined? And when do you attempt to use that type-alias?

Comment: Nod is defined right there, I'm trying to have two refferences, one to a previous Node and another one to the next Node. It's a dinamically allocated List.

Comment: No, `struct Nod` has been seen, but `Nod` isn't seen until the next line.

Comment: So is there a way to make it work?

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> typedef struct Nod {
>     Garden* info;
>     Nod* next, * prev;
> }Nod;
> ```

The type `Nod` does not exist before the final `;`, especially on the 3rd line above. You need

```
     struct Nod* next, * prev;
```

where, even though `struct Nod` is not defined yet, you can use pointers to it.

Comment: This worked after a rebuild, thanks!